# SOLR query to get list of synonyms in solr

Tags: solr

I need to get list of synonyms from synonyms.tx file  in solr for the auto suggest.
ex: synonyms.txt

fun, entertainment => recreation.

if I query for recreation, it should just give the synonyms (not the entire field) like:

recreation
fun
entertainment

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new synonyms : recreation => entertainment, fun

Comment: Manpreet Singh, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).